# Unable to connect to the Internet using wired connection, even when its plugged in

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

I recently clean installed Ubuntu without dual boot, so everything was erased, but now I'm unable to connect to the Internet, even using wired connection. On "Connection Information", it says it is "Active Network Connections" but I can't get online. Here are the results of some commands that I found online:

```
ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:54:2a:b5:fd  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:54ff:fe2a:b5fd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:138 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15637 (15.6 KB)  TX bytes:337255 (337.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:502340 (502.3 KB)  TX bytes:502340 (502.3 KB)

----------------------------------------------
sudo lshw -C network

*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:23:54:2a:b5:fd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fcfff000-fcffffff memory:fcfe0000-fcfeffff memory:fea00000-fea0ffff
------------------------------------------------
sudo ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:54:2a:b5:fd  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:54ff:fe2a:b5fd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:410 errors:0 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1799 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:43699 (43.6 KB)  TX bytes:345354 (345.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:613180 (613.1 KB)  TX bytes:613180 (613.1 KB)

--------------------------------------------------
lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2

0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2108]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
---------------------------------------------------
cat/etc/network/interfaces
bash: cat/etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
---------------------------------------------------
 cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
-----------------------------------------------------
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
--------------------------------------------
cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
------------------------------------------
 sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
----------------------------------
cat syslog
cat: syslog: No such file or directory
```

Please help me, thank you very much

Comment: You have no route to destinations other than your own subnet 10.41.0.0. Try this: `sudo ip route add 0.0.0.0/32 via 10.41.0.254` (or whatever the IP address for your Internet gateway is).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your ethernet has an IP address, the very unusual 10.42.0.1. That suggests that the ethernet is set to be shared with another computer on the network; instead, it should be set to ask for and receive an IP address from your router, switch or other access point.

Please click the Network Manager icon, select 'Edit Connections,' highlight the ethernet connection and select 'Edit.' Select IPv4 settings and make sure it is set to 'Automatic (DHCP).'

[image]

Restart Network Manager from the terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?

Comment: No. There is always a "Disconnected - you are now offline" popping up, and I still can't connect to the Internet.

Comment: Is there now an IP address consistent with other devices on your network? 192.168.x.y or some such? Or is it still 10.42.0.1?